# Convert [xcode]foo[/xcode] to <pre>foo</pre>

Tags: plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I'm converting vBulletin content to WP with the [Crayon syntax highlighter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/). What is the best way to convert the content's `[xcode]foo[/xcode]` to `<pre class="lang:default decode:true ">foo</pre>` for Crayon?

I see info about the [Crayon legacy tags conversion](http://aramk.com/2012/09/26/converting-legacy-tags-to-pre.html) but the screenshots are missing and I don't know how to enable "legacy tags" for Crayon.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Just add your own shortcode (put this into your themes functions.php or as a plugin):

```
function my_shortcode_xcode_handler( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<pre class="lang:default decode:true ">'. do_shortcode($content) .'</pre>';
}
add_shortcode( 'xcode', 'my_shortcode_xcode_handler' );
```